# How to query data across multi databases?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, hadoop, hbase

I have several `sqlserver` and `mysql` db's. And it's impossible join two or more tables between them.

A thought is to use `Hbase` on `hadoop` to achieve this by storing all columns that I need to join. Cause I don't need ad-hoc query and just need sync data to HDFS per day.

But I'm not sure if Hbase is well-suited for that considering I have to filter rows by many conditions.

Does anyone have a suggestion about this?

Comment: You can link MySQL to MSSQL https://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/

Comment: @nvartak I could not do that link on production env and some mysql db is distribution. So I have to store all data on something like HDFS. I just curious if Hbase suit for many conditions filter, Or I need to use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sqoop to import databases from sqlserver and mysql to HDFS, and then use Hive to query the imported data. Hive supports SQL and you'd be able to execute JOIN with Hive.

I don't think you can do JOINs with HBase.

Comment: HBase itself does **NOT** support SQL; but with Phoenix on top of HBase you can do *some* SQL...